# jQuery Grails Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, grails

I'm trying to install the jQuery plugin for Grails. Now I have a path and an include but it's pointing to `js/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.js`. I would like to change this. Following the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery) I should add

```
jquery {
    sources = ''
    version = '1.4.4'
}
```

To my `Config.groovy` file. Having done this I see no change. What is the correct way to change the include or do I need to simply move and rename the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ref: http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery

Add to config.groovy

```
jquery {
    sources = 'jquery' // Holds the value where to store jQuery-js files /web-app/js/
    version = '1.4.4' // The jQuery version in use
}
```

Then

```
grails clean
grails run-app
```

It work for me

Answer (score 2):

You can also download Jquery from it's site and then put it in your web-app/js. 
Next simply include it on top of your page or in your layout.gsp with something like..

`<script type="text/javascript" src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jQuery-144.js')}"></script>`

That's all there is to start using jQuery.

Hope it helps..

Comment: +1 because this plugin simply didn't work for me either for some reason and jquery is pretty easy to use anyway. It doesn't pull in jquery libraries, and the ones it links to give 404s , also resource not found errors at the console.